# Splsda with 2 y variables

Tags: r, pca

Can you do a splsda with 2 y variables ?

When I run it with y as a dataframe I get an error.

pl <- splsda(endtestrel, Y, ncomp=5, scale=T) #scale = T: centering + scaling

with Y being a dataframe with 2 columns

Y <- cbind(temp_all$cultivar,temp_all$Exp)

Comment: No, the documents state that Y has to be a vector. Could you run each column separately? You haven't given us enough information to explain what you're trying to do, or why, so it is impossible to give you any advice other than to answer your question with a straightforward "no", this function does not allow two Y variables.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.